# nested Condition in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

my `AsyncTask` `doInBackground` have multiple nested condition which return `String` to `onPostExectue` method , which make code very complex is there any alternative way to handle this problem

Now my code look like this

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params){
    if (position == 0){ 
         return "Set1" 
    }
    else if(Position >something) { 
         return set 2 
    } .........and so on 
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (result.equals("set1")){
       // do some taskk
    }
    elseif(result.equal("Set2")){
        // do other task
    }
    else if(){
       // sooo onnnnnn
     }
}
```

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can try to apply [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern here. You can create an abstract class, say `Action`, with an abstract function `perform()`. Then you can create concrete subclasses of `Action` for every action which can be performed in onPostExecute. So you have classes say `ActionForSet1`, `ActinForSet2`  etc with concrete implementations of perform(). Then `Action` should have a static method `String Action createfromString(String set)` which will be essentially the same if/else or break but much more maintainable. It will return corresponding Action subclasses for every string. You can use Map instead of if/else in there, easier to add/remove elements then. Then after you have your `Action` object returned by `Action.createFromString` you call its `perform()`

```
onPostExecute(String result) {
   Action a = Action.actionForResult(result);
   a.perform();
}

abstract class Action {
  abstract void perform();

  static Action actionForResult(String result) {
      if(result.equals("res1") {
          return new ActionForRes1();
      } else if(result.equals("res2") {
          return new ActionForRes2();
      } else throw new IllegalArgumentException("No action for result " + result);
   }
}

class ActionForResult1 extends Action {
  @Override
  void perform() { Log.i("ACTION", "Here's action for result 1"); }
}

class ActionForResult2 extends Action {
  @Override
  void perform() { Log.i("ACTION", "Here's action for result 2"); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice OO way to simplify your code that involves conditionals is by replacing them by means of the Strategy pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). You can find some info about this particular refactoring here: http://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/conditionalWithStrategy.html.

The basic idea is to encapsulate the logic of each conditional case with a strategy and delegate to the strategy instance instead. This produces much more clear code than nested if/then/else or switch statements.

To illustrate this point, let's assume you have a complex conditional logic such as this one:

```
Entity e = // some entity
if ("TypeOne".equals(e.getType()) {
  // process entity of type one...
} else if ("TypeTwo".equals(e.getType()) {
  // process entity of type two...
} else if ("TypeThree".equals(e.getType()) {
  // process entity of type three...
} else {
  // default processing logic
}
```

Instead of writing this piece of logic procedurally, we could use the Strategy pattern to decompose it into different entity processing strategies. First we need to define an interface which will be shared from all entity processing strategies:

```
public interface EntityProcessingStrategy {
  public void process(Entity e);
}
```

Then we create a concrete strategy implementation for each of our conditional cases, encapsulating the specific processing logic:

```
public class TypeOneEntityProcessingStrategy {
  public void process(Entity e) {
    // process entity of type one...
  }
}

public class TypeTwoEntityProcessingStrategy {
  public void process(Entity e) {
    // process entity of type two...
  }
}

public class TypeThreeEntityProcessingStrategy {
  public void process(Entity e) {
    // process entity of type three...
  }
}

public class DefaultEntityProcessingStrategy {
  public void process(Entity e) {
    // default entity processing logic...
  }
}
```

Our previous code could be thus simplified removing the conditionals, like so:

```
Entity e = // our entity that needs to be processed
EntityProcessingStrategy strategy = EntityProcessingStrategies.getStrategyFor(e.getType);
strategy.process(e);
```

Note that in my last example i have included an EntityProcessingStrategies class which serves as a factory of concrete strategies. More specifically, it can be something like:

```
public final class EntityProcessingStrategies {

  private EntityProcessingStrategies() { }

  public EntityProcessingStrategy getStrategyFor(String type) {
    if ("TypeOne".equals(type)) return new TypeOneEntityProcessingStrategy();
    if ("TypeTwo".equals(type)) return new TypeTwoEntityProcessingStrategy();
    if ("TypeThree".equals(type)) return new TypeThreeEntityProcessingStrategy();
    return new DefaultEntityProcessingStrategy();
  }
}
```

This is one way to create concrete strategy instances but it's by no means the only way.

Answer (score 0):

if you have only use this type of flow then

```
if(){
}
else if(){
}
else if(){
}
```

then the alternate is switch case for they type of flow. You need to return as integer instead of String from doInBackground() and use integer value in switch.

```
switch(result){
case 0:
    break;
case 1:
    break;
....
}
```

As you mention here nested. Its not really a nested. nested one of the block have also if condition like

```
if(){
}
else{
    if(){
    }
    else{
        if(){
        } and so on..
    }
}
```